# Using pumping lemma to show $L = \{a^i b^j a^k \ | \ k > i + j\}$ cannot be accepted by an FA

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma, check-my-answer

> $L = \{a^i b^j a^k \ | \ k > i + j\}$
>
> Use the pumping lemma to show that this language cannot be accepted by an FA.

**Proof:**

Suppose $L$ can be accepted by an FA.

Suppose a string $s = xyz \in L$, where

$$\begin{align} 
&x=a^n \\
&y=b \\
&z=a^{n+2} 
\end{align}
$$.

Then a string $t = a^n b^i a^{n+2}$ should also be in $L$ for $i \ge 0$, $n+i<n+2$ and should also be accepted by an FA. But if $i=3$,

$$\begin{align} n+i = n + 3 \\>n + 2 \end{align}$$

and $t \not \in L$, which is a contradiction. Thus, $L$ cannot be accepted by an FA.

---

Is this proof thorough? I am worried about the line $n+i<n+2$, because it doesn't work for all values of $i$. Should I pick a string that works for all possible cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your basic idea (in particular the choice of $t$) works, but there are some issues with the "proof" as such:

- What is $n$?
- Why do you have $y=b$ have to be pumped? You have to work against *all* allowed decompositions of $t$!
- $n+i < n+2$ does indeed not work for all $i$, but that's kind of the point. Just drop that condition.

I suggest you read our [reference posts](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular) about how to read and apply the Pumping lemma properly, and then browse our [pumping-lemma](/questions/tagged/pumping-lemma) questions for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that *n* is the number of states in your FA
and you chose your string so the length of *x* is equal to or greater than *n*

in Which case you have to remember that one of the conditions for the pumping lemma is that the length of the string *xy* is equal to or smaller than *n*.

this means that if you choose $t=\{a^n b^i a^{2n}\}$,
*y* cannot contain any *b*'s since $a^n$ has to be in *xy*.